# How to read a JSON file using Nix?

Tags: json, nix

How can I read a JSON file that exists in the filesystem with Nix? Is this natively supported?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we have a file `example.json` like:

```
{
  "rev": "fcc9a7714053acb1aaf6913b99b6f49e0d13b1b7"
}
```

We can use the following where `fromJSON` will return an attribute set:

```
nix-repl> v = builtins.fromJSON (builtins.readFile "/path/to/example.json")        
nix-repl> v.rev
"fcc9a7714053acb1aaf6913b99b6f49e0d13b1b7"
```

Comment: You could use `lib.importJSON`, which is defined in terms of the same builtins.